# NoReverseMatch at /view_clients/

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Quero imprimir uma ficha simples de um cliente dentro de uma lista de clientes que cadastrei na aplicação. Quando clico no link para gerar me retorna esse erro:

*NoReverseMatch at /view_clients/*

*Reverse for 'cliente' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view_clients\/client_id\:id$']*

**urls.py do projeto:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
app_name = 'app_web_gym'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app_web_gym.urls', namespace='app_web_gym'))
]
```

**urls.py da aplicação:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'app_web_gym'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('view_clients/', views.clientes, name='clientes'),
    path('view_clients/client_id:id', views.cliente, name='cliente'),

]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cliente

def index(request):
    """A página inicial de Web Gym"""
    return render(request, 'app_web_gym/index.html')

def clientes(request):
    clientes = Cliente.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'clientes': clientes}
    return render(request, 'app_web_gym/view_clients.html', context)

def cliente(request, client_id):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=client_id)
    last_name = cliente.last_name
    context = {'cliente': cliente, 'last_name': last_name}
    return render (request, 'app_web_gym/cliente.html', context)
```

**base.html:**

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:index' %}">Web Gym</a>
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:clientes' %}">Clientes</a>
</p>

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

**view_clients.html:**

```
{% extends 'app_web_gym/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Clientes</p>
    <ul>
        {% for cli in clientes %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:cliente' cli.id %}">{{cli}}</a>
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>Nenhum cliente para mostrar.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

**clientes.html:**

```
{% extends 'app_web_gym/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Cliente</p>
    <p>{{cliente}} {{last_name}}</p>


{% endblock content %}
```

Desculpem qualquer erro. Estou iniciando em django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas coisas a mudar:

Nos teus `urlpatterns` tens de corrigir para:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('view_clients/', views.clientes, name='clientes'),
    path('view_clients/<int:client_id>/', views.cliente, name='cliente'),

]
```

E no template para:

```
<a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:cliente' client_id=cli.id %}">{{cli}}</a>
```